# html2pdf package gets very slow when html page size is big or number of pages is more

Tags: html, reactjs, angular, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf npm package in my project to convert html to pdf, its working fine for 1 or 2 page but when the number of pages increases it takes 7 to 8 minutes to convert. Any help would be appreciable.

```
const DownloadPDF = () => { 
  var opt = { margin: [10, 5, 10, 5], filename: "chart.pdf", //image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 }, html2canvas: { scale: 2, letterRendering: true }, jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }, }; 
  let pages = []; 
  for (let j = 1; j < pages.length; j++) { 
    pages.push(document.getElementById("graph" + j)); 
  }
  let doc = html2pdf().set(opt).from(pages[0]).toPdf() 
  for (let j = 1; j < pages.length; j++) { 
    doc = doc.get('pdf').then( pdf => { pdf.addPage();
  } ).from(pages[j]).toContainer().toCanvas().toPdf() } doc.save(); 
}
```

Comment: show some code, so that we can identify a bottleneck

Comment: i have added the code in the question plz check